# RF transmitter circuit explanation

Tags: rf, passive-networks

I just can't get my head around how these RF transmitters work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjrCGE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What I do know about them is the following, correct me if I am wrong. L1 and C4 form resonant system, which without other parts of the circuit would slow down due to dissipated energy. I am also aware that Q1 is operated in forward active region, but why? Also what's the purpose of C5? Why with this setup L1 and C4 keep on going?

Comment: Is this the complete circuit? OR did you forget to add an ac source?

Comment: @nidhin I'm sure the AC source is back of R1 and Also, plus a decoupling capacitor.

Comment: This is just an unmodulated RF transmitter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, the circuit shown is just a carrier wave generator - it's an oscillator that produces a constant sine wave; there is no provision to be able to modulate that carrier because there is no defined input to do that. So, rather than a transmitter, I'd call it a beacon - it generates a fixed carrier wave with no modulation.

Generally, you can put a small AC voltage on the biased base with respect to the emitter of a BJT circuit and you will likely get an amplified version of this at the collector. This is usually called a common emitter amplifier but if you think about it, you can also hold the biased base voltage steady and wobble the emitter a bit and you will get the same voltage amplification. This is a common base amplifier.

Why choose the emitter for an input - if you held the emitter constant and applied a small positive pulse to the base, the BJT would turn on a bit more and the collector voltage would produce an amplified negative going pulse. Whereas, if you held the base constant and applied a small positive pulse to the emitter you'd be slightly shutting-off the BJT and this would produce a positive pulse on the collector. In other words, the voltage at the collector is an in-phase amplified version of the voltage applied to the emitter in common-base configuration.

It's the opposite on the base and hence positive feedback cannot be achieved with a simple capacitor like C5 but, it's positive feedback on the emitter and thus will help the tuned-circuit sustain its sine wave.

Comment: Ah, I understand it better now. But just how in current/voltage terms, does positive feedback work, how does it help it sustain its sine wave?

Comment: Having roughly the "correct" amount of positive feedback (plus a few circuit non-linearities that help modify that "correct" amount of positive feedback) is the key and not really hard to achieve. Get the positive feedback about right and the losses in the tuned circuit (and transistor) are overcome and it oscillates continuously as if losses were not there at all.

Answer (score 3):

> How exactly? It seems like at high frequencies that C5 provides a
>   low-impedance short to the emitter, but I am not quite sure how that
>   is positive feedback.

The [common-base amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_base) is non-inverting and input voltage is applied to the emitter.

Since the input impedance of a CB amplifier is relatively low, the CB amp is approximately a non-inverting [transimpedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transimpedance_amplifier) amplifier.

Since the output of the CB is taken from the collector, the impedance of C5 and R2 form a feedback network from the output (collector) to the input (emitter).  And, since the amplifier is non-inverting, this is *positive* feedback.

It's an error to assume that the impedance of C5 as negligible (a "low-impedance short") at the oscillation frequency.

Answer (score 1):

If you read up about "common base" amplifiers you will see how this works, and understand that C5 provides positive feedback from collector (output) to emitter(input).

As for why the transistor is in the "forward active region" that is because R1 provides base current to bias the transistor active (turn it on).

Comment: How is the emitter an input to the system?

Comment: It isn't an input to the system; it's the input to the gain stage (subsystem - mainly Q1), which is why the positive feedback is connected to it.

Comment: How exactly? It seems like at high frequencies that C5 provides a low-impedance short to the emitter, but I am not quite sure how that is positive feedback.

Comment: Once you understand the common-base amplifier you will see why C5 provides positive feedback. NB: C1 grounds the base (at high frequencies)